# Proofs not working in custom environment (LaTeX)

Tags: latex

I've been using LaTeX for school for about 6 months now, so I'm not extremely experienced.  The first class I was required to use it for gave us a template to use for assignments, which I just used blindly without really understanding.  I used it for much more than that class, and have come to like it quite a bit.

Unfortunately, I'm now using LaTeX for a class centered around proofs, and the amsthm package feature `\begin{proof}` doesn't work within the custom environment created in the template.  I spent about an hour looking for solutions and doing my own trouble shooting before I narrowed it down to the template (When I comment out that custom environment's creation and use the problem is solved).

The `\begin{proof}` correctly places and formats the qed symbol, but does *not* put the word "*Proof:*" in place.  Is there a simple edit that can be made to this custom environment which would allow that feature to work properly?  Here is the environment declaration:
`\newenvironment{problems}{\begin{list}{}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{.7in}}}{\end{list}}`

Comment: Please make a *compilable* [mre] which allows us to reproduce the problem. If this mysterious class is necessary to reproduce the problem, please also indicate where it is available from.

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newenvironment{problems}{\begin{list}{}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{.7in}}}{\end{list}}

\usepackage{amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,graphicx}

\graphicspath{./images/} \begin{document}

\begin{problems}

Problem 2: Prove or disprove: Lorem Ipsum.
\\\begin{proof}
This does not work
\end{proof}

\end{problems}

\end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not ignore error messages!

For some unknown reason you define your `problems` environment as a list. Consequently you must at least use one `\item` within the environment. An error in your .log file will clearly tell you about the missing `\item`.

There is no point in even looking at the output as long as you have errors in your document. After an error, latex just recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document, not necessarily producing sensible output.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  

\newenvironment{problems}{\begin{list}{}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{.7in}}}{\end{list}} 

\usepackage{amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,graphicx} 

\graphicspath{./images/} 

\begin{document}  

\begin{problems}  
\item Problem 2: Prove or disprove: Lorem Ipsum. 

\begin{proof} 
This does not work 
\end{proof}  

\end{problems}  

\end{document}
```

[image]